# Let $V=M(2,\mathbb{R})$. For a given matrix $A\in V$ define a linear operator $T_A$ on V by $T_A:V\to V\; T_A(M)=AM-MA$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V=M(2,\mathbb{R})$. For a given matrix $A\in V$ define a linear operator  $T_A$ on V by $T_A:V\to V\; T_A(M)=AM-MA$

Let $M=\begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 0  \\
        0 & 2 \\
        \end{pmatrix}$  . Determine the eigenvalues  of $T_A$ and the associated  eigenspace . Determine the minimal polynomial of $T_A$

How we solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** The standard basis, namely
$$
\pmatrix{1&0\\0&0}, \quad
\pmatrix{0&1\\0&0}, \quad
\pmatrix{0&0\\1&0}, \quad
\pmatrix{0&0\\0&1}
$$
consists of eigenvectors of this transformation.